# Hiding columns in a table if a condition is met

Tags: php, html

I am using the below table for 3 conditions, by passing values through variables.

In one of my conditions I have only 3 colums, i.e `$h2` will be empty for one condition. `if($h2=="")` I want to hide that entire column.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
<table id="usertracking" >
<thead>
<tr>
<?php   
echo'<td><h3>'.$h1.'<h3></td>'; 
echo'<td><h3>'.$h2.'<h3></td>';
echo'<td><h3>'.$h3.'<h3></td>';
echo'<td><h3>'.$h4.'<h3></td>';                     
?>  
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php
        for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++)
        {
            echo'<tr>'; 
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['MpwName'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientName'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientAddress'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['New'].'</td>';
            echo'<tr>';
        }   
        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to hide the entire row ? or column ?

Comment: What code have you tried to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `$h2` is empty. If not, print:

```
<table id="usertracking" >
<thead>
<tr>
<?php   
echo'<td><h3>'.$h1.'<h3></td>'; 
if (!empty($h2))                        // check
    echo'<td><h3>'.$h2.'<h3></td>';     // print
echo'<td><h3>'.$h3.'<h3></td>';
echo'<td><h3>'.$h4.'<h3></td>';                     
?>  
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php
        for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++)
        {
            echo'<tr>'; 
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['MpwName'].'</td>';
            if (!empty($h2))                                  // check
                echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientName'].'</td>'; // print
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientAddress'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['New'].'</td>';
            echo'<tr>';
        }   
        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like :

```
$display_column1=$display_column2=$display_column3=$display_column4=true;
if($h1=="")$display_column1=false;
if($h2=="")$display_column2=false;
...
echo'<tr>'; 
if($display_column1)echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['MpwName'].'</td>';
if($display_column2)echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientName'].'</td>';
...
```

And better, make this in loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your if condition before each echo that you need:

```
//in the Head
if ($h2) echo'<td><h3>'.$h2.'<h3></td>';
```

And in the body, at the column data:

```
if ($h2) echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientName'].'</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of CSS and PHP, you might try something like

```
<td style="display:<?/*Your condition here*/?>;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
//in the Head
if ($h2 != ""){ echo'<td><h3>'.$h2.'<h3></td>'; }

// in loop
if ($h2!= ""){ echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['PatientName'].'</td>'; }
```